# Trying to simplify a query of a single table

Tags: sql, inner-join, sqlanywhere

I have a table from SQLAnywhere (Netbackup) that I am trying to query in a way that will help a shell script decide if a rerun is required our not. Netbackup will naturally try to rerun the job so its possible a job could fail a couple times then run successfully later in the 12 hour window. The I am calling is domain_job and I am trying to query for a specific status code (4275) within a 12 hours period and as long as there are 3 counts of the status code and no count of a 0 return code within the 12 hour window. I need it to list this output so the script can run it. I tried a nested select but the count seems wrong.

This select returns data but I can't figure out how to best interject the count of the status code to make sure 3 backups have failed since a 0 and show the most recent job ID so it can be rerun by the shell script. Also not sure the count is returning correctly.

```
SELECT a.clientName, a.job_count, MAX(id)
FROM (SELECT clientName, COUNT(statusCode) AS job_count
FROM domain_job
 where statusCode = 4275
  AND type = 28
  AND (policyName LIKE '%vip%' OR policyName LIKE '%VIP%')
  AND datediff(HOUR, UTCBigIntToNOMTime(endTime), getdate()) < 12
GROUP BY clientName
ORDER BY clientName, job_count DESC ) a, domain_job b
 where a.clientName=b.clientName
  AND b.statusCode = 4275
  AND b.type = 28
  AND (b.policyName LIKE '%vip%' OR b.policyName LIKE '%VIP%')
  AND datediff(HOUR, UTCBigIntToNOMTime(b.endTime), getdate()) < 12
GROUP BY client_name
```

This select works but its seems convoluted.

````
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Failures",
       d.clientName AS "Client"
FROM domain_Job d
WHERE clientName IN (
    SELECT clientName
    FROM domain_Job c
    WHERE c.id IN (
        -- Get the Max Job ID with out filtering for Status Code.
        -- This will then be used to get the final result of backups
        -- We will see if backups have reran successfully or not.
        SELECT MAX(b.id)
        FROM domain_job b
        WHERE b.clientName IN (
            -- Get the initial client names of backups that have failed in
            -- XX hours ago with 4275, this is the seed.
            SELECT a.clientName
            FROM domain_job a
            WHERE a.statusCode = 4275
              AND a.type = 28
              AND (a.policyName LIKE '%vip%' OR a.policyName LIKE '%VIP%')
              AND datediff(HOUR, UTCBigIntToNOMTime(a.endTime), getdate()) < 12
            GROUP BY a.clientName
            )
          AND b.type = 28
          AND (b.policyName LIKE '%vip%' OR b.policyName LIKE '%VIP%')
          AND datediff(HOUR, UTCBigIntToNOMTime(b.endTime), getdate()) < 12
        GROUP BY b.clientName
        )
      AND c.statusCode = 4275
      AND c.type = 28
      AND (c.policyName LIKE '%vip%' OR c.policyName LIKE '%VIP%')
      AND datediff(HOUR , UTCBigIntToNOMTime(c.endTime), getdate()) < 12
    )
  AND datediff(HOUR , UTCBigIntToNOMTime(d.endTime), getdate()) < 12
GROUP BY "Client"  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "ORDER BY clientName, job_count DESC" from query a